# How do I add a CSS property on notepad++ via xml?

Tags: css, notepad++

I have the CSS rule starting with "::selection" and it works in google chrome when I run it but notepad++ says its an unknown CSS property. How can I alter the notepad++ files to add this rule and others?

Comment: Notepad++ does not support CSS3 pseudo-element syntax AFAIK.

Comment: @BoltClock Notepad++ is just a text editor, it doesn't need to *support* (whatever that means) any of CSS.

Comment: @transistor09: It's a text editor with syntax highlighting. A syntax highlighter needs to understand a language in order to highlight code written in that language. It's pretty much implied that "support" for a language in this case refers to the ability to parse and highlight code in said language, as opposed to implementing the language.

Comment: @BoltClock oh wow. It's amazing how incorrectly I read the question first time. Sorry about the commotion.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the langs.xml file, we find this:

```
<Language name="css" ext="css" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
    <Keywords name="instre1">-khtml-border-radius <!-- ... --></Keywords>
    <Keywords name="instre2">active after before <!-- ... --> selection target valid visited</Keywords>
</Language>
```

Note in particular the "instre2" section ("instre1" is a list of properties, not selectors). This seems to indicate that the "selection" keyword is indeed recognized by Notepad++'s syntax highlighter.

As indicated in the question, Notepad++ does not highlight `::selection` correctly. However, it *does* highlight `:selection` like it would `:focus` or `:before`, even though `::selection` requires double-colon syntax by virtue of being a newer pseudo-element.

Notepad++ highlights the following examples, among others, as "pseudo-classes" (both pseudo-classes and legacy pseudo-elements):

- `:first-child`
- `:focus`
- `:before`
- `:after`
- `:selection` (incorrect)

But it does not highlight the following examples as pseudo-elements:

- `::before`
- `::after`
- `::selection` (correct)

This suggests that Notepad++'s syntax highlighter simply does not recognize the CSS3 double-colon syntax for pseudo-elements. Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's anything that can be done here except to wait for a newer version of Notepad++ to support it. In fact, I would not rely on Notepad++ for checking your selector syntax as it generally does a less than stellar job at highlighting selectors.